# How to install MySql.data version 6.8.3.0

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010

When i installed my windows form application in XP OS.. it asked me to install MySql.data version 6.8.3.0. And when i searched in internet there is no **.exe file** to download and install. Could you please tell me how to install if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql.Data6.8.3 Connector/Net is a fully-managed ADO.NET driver for MySQL.

To install MySql.Data, run the following command in the Package Manager Console

PM> Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.8.3

Comment: so if i have coded my windows form application with SQL connection.. and if i want to install this application on a computer where there is no internet but.. LAN connection is there.. will the application run. Or is there any ways.. that i can connect the application to a database.. through LAN

Comment: May be you are looking for this. Please check here- [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2010/09/02/create-a-sql-server-database-on-a-network-shared-drive.aspx)

Comment: No i need.. something like. Ok.. i have a database.mdf i made in SQL workbench.. 
and i need to connect that database to the windows form application.. and if i right click my project and take properties.
 i can see a tab's like application, Build, Build events, debug.. like that there is a tab called settings.

I guess u know better than ,me. Okay so if i click that setting i can see something like 
name of conenction---> type of connection---> and the path..

Comment: so you want to deploy winform application with your .mdf file?

Comment: yes i want so what i should do to work in another system.. which are locally connected in LAN.. i tried its saying.. cannot connect to Sql server

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/05/29/working-with-a-local-data-file-in-vs.aspx                                            See here you will get some help